# Select latest data based on date column

Tags: sql, db2-400

I have a table ACCT,

```
COMPANY    ACCOUNT    EFFDT        NAME
25         1001       2015-12-01   ABC Ltd.
25         1001       2012-01-01   ABC Inc
30         1001       2012-01-01   ABC Inc
10         1001       2012-01-01   ABC Inc
10         3800       2011-05-01   RAC Corp
25         3800       2011-05-01   RAC Corp
30         3800       2011-05-01   RAC Corp
```

I am trying to get the last record for a set of accounts based on `EFFDT` column for a account #

Result I am looking for is,

```
| 25  | 1001  | 2015-12-01   | ABC Ltd.
| 30  | 3800  | 2011-05-01   | RAC Corp
```

I tried using,

```
select * 
  from acct t1 
    inner join (
        select account as a, max(effdt) as b, max(company) as c 
          from acct 
          where account in (1001, 3800) 
          group by account
        ) t2 
      on t1.account = t2.a 
        and t1.effdt = t2.b 
        and t1.company = t2.c;
```

but I only get,

```
| 30  | 3800  | 2011-05-01   | RAC Corp
```

Comment: use `row_number` to get the max row based on `effdt`

Comment: In case Effdt,  name and account # are ALL  the same, which record you will get? what is the primary key of the table.

Comment: company, account and effdt is composite key

Comment: so if in case all effdt are the same for the same account, which company to select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
select max(a.company), a.account, a.effdt, a.name from acct a
join(select account, max(EFFDT) as m  
    from acct 
    group by account)
b on a.account = b.account and a.EFFDT = m  
group by a.account, a.effdt, a.name
```

Answer (score 2):

using `ROW_NUMBER`

https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-use-row_number-in-db2/

```
  SELECT
      company,
      account,
      effdt,
      name
    FROM (SELECT
      company,
      account,
      effdt,
      name,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY account ORDER BY effdt DESC, company DESC) rn  
    FROM acct) x
    WHERE x.rn = 1
```

Comment: the rn is not 1. So when I use x.rn = 1.. I am not getting any records

Comment: rn is the row number according to the partition and order by... it resets if it sees another account. there will always be rn = 1 provided that there is data

Comment: jump to `rextester.com` or `sqlfiddle.com` and create your data then run the script